# Play/Pause multiple video with one function

Tags: javascript, html

I can currently play and pause a video by clicking anywhere in the `<video>` tag.But unfortunately, when i have added a second video the function works only for the first video only.

```js
 var video = document.getElementById('vid');
    video.addEventListener('click', function() {
                this.paused?this.play():this.pause();
            },
            false);

    video.addEventListener("pause", function() {
        document.getElementById("paused").style.display = "";
    });
    video.addEventListener("play", function() {
        document.getElementById("paused").style.display = "none";
    });
```

```html
<div id="main">

  <div id="computer" class="content">
    <div style="margin-left:8%">
      <div id="paused" style="display: none">QUESTION HERE</div>
      <video width="1000" height="480" id="vid">
        <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
          Your browser does not support the video tag.
      </video>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div id="ip" class="content">
    <div style="margin-left:8%">
      <div id="paused" style="display: none">QUESTION HERE</div>
      <video width="1000" height="480" id="vid">
        <source src="video2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
          Your browser does not support the video tag.
      </video>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any issue with the js code. Kindly advice.

Comment: **The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the value must be unique within the HTML document).** http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp

Comment: You must not have more than one element with the same id in one document.

Comment: oh yes, true. But how i can accomplish this task?

Comment: Turn the IDs into classes.

Answer (score 0):

it will not work lake that because ,the interpreter will consider just the last id with the same element ,if you use just two videos then you can just add other video id and paused id

```
<div id="ip" class="content">
<div style="margin-left:8%">
  <div id="paused2" style="display: none">QUESTION HERE</div>
  <video width="1000" height="480" id="vid2">
    <source src="video2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
</div>
```

Comment: i have a lot of videos on the same page, that would be a lot of duplication

Answer (score 0):

try to use classes instud of ids
for more detaill take a lok to this page
http://flash.flowplayer.org/demos/installation/multiple-players.html